# Edit component does not change the value of the item in the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

So I am working on my first To Do List in React, and my head cannot get around an issue here. When I edit the input of to do item, it stays the same. I am including my whole app snippet:

```
import { DeleteButton } from './Delete-Button';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { EditButton } from './Edit'

export function Task({ item, onDelete, onEdit }) {
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  function handleDeleteClick () {
    onDelete(item.id);
  };
  function handleEditClick (taskId,EditedItem) {
    onEdit(taskId,EditedItem);
    setIsEditing(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <li>
        {isEditing ? (
          <EditButton item={item} onEdit={handleEditClick} />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <span>{item.item}</span>
            <button onClick={() => setIsEditing(true)}>Edit</button>
          </div>
        )}
        <DeleteButton onClick={handleDeleteClick} />
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function EditText({ text }) {
  const [editedText, setEditedText] = useState(text);

  const handleTextChange = (event) => {
    setEditedText(event.target.value);

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={editedText} onChange={handleTextChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { EditText } from './EditText';

export function EditButton({ item, onEdit }) {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editedItem, setEditedItem] = useState(item);

  const handleEditClick = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  const handleSaveClick = () => {
    setIsEditing(false);
    onEdit({ ...item, item: editedItem.item });
  };

  const handleCancelClick = () => {
    setIsEditing(false);
    setEditedItem(item);
  };

  const handleTextChange = (event) => {
    setEditedItem({ ...editedItem, item:event.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isEditing ? (
        <div>
          <EditText text={editedItem.item} onChange={handleTextChange} />
          <button onClick={handleSaveClick}>Save</button>
          <button onClick={handleCancelClick}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <span>{item.item}</span>
          <button onClick={handleEditClick}>Edit</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { AddTask } from './components/Add-Task';
import {itemsList} from "./listArray";
import { Task } from './components/TaskElement';





function ToDoList() {
  const [todos,setTodos] = useState([...itemsList]);
  

  const handleAddTask = (newTask) => {
    const lastId = todos.length > 0 ? todos[todos.length - 1].id : 0;
    const newId = lastId + 1;
    const newTaskObj = { id: newId, item: newTask };
    setTodos([...todos, newTaskObj]);
  };
  
    function handleDeleteTask(taskId) {
      const updatedTodos = todos.filter((item) => item.id !== taskId);
      setTodos(updatedTodos);
    }

    const handleEditTask = (taskId, editedText) => {
      const updatedTasks = todos.map((task) => {
        if (task.id === taskId) {
          return { ...task, text: editedText };
        }
        return task;
      });
      setTodos(updatedTasks);
    };
   
  return (
    <>
      <AddTask onAdd={handleAddTask}/>
        <ul>
          {todos.map(task => 
          <>
            <Task 
            key={task.id}
            item={task} 
            onDelete= {()=> handleDeleteTask(task.id)}
            onEdit ={handleEditTask}/> 
            </>
          )}
        </ul>

    </>
          )
  
}

export default ToDoList;
```

I tried modifying my component here and there, and no results yet.
I am using an array of objects that have 2 attributes: id and item.

Comment: You never use `EditText` anywhere. There is no list in the code

Comment: @Konrad Added the code for EditButton component. 
There

Comment: You never use the `onChange` prop

Comment: @Konrad can you elaborate please?
As I see I am using onChange in Task component for EditText comp.

Comment: You pass it here `<EditText text={editedItem.item} onChange={handleTextChange} />`, but you don't use it here `export function EditText({ text }) {`